# Is there a way to make a console application appear over other processes

Tags: windows, console, c#-3.0

I'm currently making a custom crosshair console application and trying to figure out how make the application appear over the game screen and other processes with the addition to hide it with a hotkey. My problem is I can't seem to figure out how to make the application appear over other windows.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

first import your required dependencies

then insert the following code into your main class

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             IntPtr hWnd = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;

                SetWindowPos(hWnd,
                    new IntPtr(HWND_TOPMOST),
                    0, 0, 0, 0,
                    SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
            
        }
```